# EventHandler not firing when placed into usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have code that renders a delete button with an event handler. With the code placed in the .aspx.cs of the form, then event handler fires and everything works fine. When I move the code to a usercontrol, I click the delete button and it pops up the confirm message, doesn't do anything else. It doesn't run, you can't run it in the debugger etc.

The doDelete278T function is in the user control.

Why doesn't C# run the `doDelete278T` function when the code is in a usercontrol?

Code Sample:

```cs
try
{
    SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    int j = 0;
    short tabby = 32;
    if (r.HasRows)
        pnl_278t.Visible = true;

    while (r.Read())
    {
        LinkButton lbt = new LinkButton();
        lbt.ID = "delete_" + r[_folderName + "_FT278T_UID"].ToString();
        lbt.CausesValidation = false;
        lbt.Text = "X";
        lbt.Click += new EventHandler(doDelete278T);
        lbt.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this 278T Record?')";
        lbt.TabIndex = tabby++;

        pnl_add278t.Controls.Add(lbt);
        pnl_add278t.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp;"));
        j++;
    }//end while
    //tbx_278T_count.Text = j.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I've seen this kind of question many times but never had to deal with it (sry in advance), but I'm wondering, with the user control, and the new buttons and the Page, and all that going on, if adding `this` makes any difference here? `lbt.Click += new EventHandler(this.doDelete278T);`.

Comment: Just came across this and seem to recall this answer coming up many times before. Not positive it's relevant here but worth a shot. [Link](https://forums.asp.net/t/1189782.aspx?button+click+event+not+firing+on+dynamic+usercontrol). Answer near the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

My actual problem turned out be that the control load logic needed to be run when the button was clicked like it is in the page where the button handler is right in the aspx.cs.

Old ascx.cs Page_Load
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        do278TLoad();
    }
}
```

New ascx.cs Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _tbx_uid        = (TextBox)this.Parent.Parent.FindControl("pnl_vars").FindControl("tbx_uid");
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (_tbx_uid.Text != "0")
            {
                do278TLoad();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            do278TLoad();
        }
    }
```